# Azure ARM policy assignment error - api-version s invalid

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to run a simple command to assign an arm policy to a resource group.

My command to create the definitions works fine, and my assignment commands work fine when using a scubscription scope.

However, when I try to run the command I get the following error:

> 2017-06-26 18:28:59,248 - configuration.policyassignment - ERROR - The
>   command failed, producing the following error: ERROR: The api-version
>   '2016-04-01' is invalid. The supported versions are
>   '2017-06-01,2017-05-10,2017-05-01,2017-03-01,2016-09-01,2016-07-01,2016-06-01,2016-02-01,2015-11-01,2015-01-01,2014-04-01-preview,2014-04-01,2014-01-01,2013-03-01,2014-02-26,2014-04'.

The command I am trying to run is:

```
az policy assignment create --name permittedResourceTypes --policy netPermittedResourceTypes --scope /subscriptions/<sub id>/test-rg
```

ANy ideas what might be causing the error?

Comment: When you execute azure cli command, you could not use specific API version, I guess you don't use the latest version cli. I test in my lab, you command works for me. You could check my answer.